# CosmosDb table retrieve multiple records at once

Tags: multithreading, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

I am looking at doing multiple point read operations at a time (they do belong to the same partition, and I do not intend retrieving more than 100 at a time). The requirements are really quite simple. The Cloud table does not support retrieving more than one entity at a time, and I am really at my wits end about how to proceed.

I could create a Table query with the partition key, and all the row keys that are of interest, but that really seems like an overkill. I know exactly what I am looking for. I also do not want to end up scanning the entire partition.

This is what I have done. I however do not know if the CloudTable client is thread safe.

```
List<Task<TableResult>> taskList = new List<Task<TableResult>>();
CloudTable cloudTable = ...;
foreach (T entity in readContainer.Entities)
{
    taskList.Add(cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Retrieve<T> 
                                              (entity.PartitionKey,
                                               entity.RowKey)));
}
Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
IList<TableResult> results = new List<TableResult>();
foreach (Task<TableResult> task in taskList)
{
    results.Add(task.Result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudTable is thread safe.

CloudTable batch API can be leveraged in above scenarios. Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.executebatch?view=azure-dotnet